Вытянуть конкретные данные из ячейки Google таблицы
Как вытащить из заявки нужную мне кол-во часов, если заказчик меняет шаблон вставляя лишний пробел или знак. Пример:
Дата: 30.05.2024
Кол-во часов: 3
Кол-во мест: 15
ФИО: Иванов

Бывает:
Дата: 30.05.2024
Кол-во часов : *3
Кол-во мест: 15
ФИО: Иванов

Бывает:
Дата: 30.05.2024
Кол-во часов :5
Кол-во мест: 15
ФИО: Иванов

Мне нужно вытащить только цифру, кол-во часов в отдельную ячейку в таблице! Пробовал формулу =REGEXEXTRACT(H2;"часов:(.+)"), вытаскивает только при чётком написании Кол-во часов:3, если прописано по другому выдаёт #N/A. Как можно прописать формулу что бы не зависимо от написания вытащил цифру не зависимо от пробела или знака перед цифрой.
